# how to get server to client response time in miliseconds while testing websocket API

Tags: api, websocket, performance-testing

how can I get exact travel time from server to client in miliseconds of each live data I am getting while testing Websocket API... I am using postman to connect API and to fetch live data feed...and jmeter to get avarage response time ?

[image: i just wants to know the response time in HH:MM:SS:sss format]

i am taking jmeter average response time as respone time for each data ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter's "average response time" is basically [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean): sum of all response times divided by their count.

Check [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for metrics descriptions and [Calculator](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) source code to see the formulae.

Also you can get rid of Postman completely, JMeter can be used for testing the  WebSockets including load testing with a [plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers): [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)